# Use 10 inch network patch panel with 19 inch switch

Tags: brackets, ethernet

I have 10 network outlets throughout the house that terminate in the basement. I got a [16-port switch](http://amzn.eu/0thq6w5) for them to plug into, going via a [12-port patch panel](http://amzn.eu/dX7UlI2).

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to rack mount the patch panel and the switch as they're different sizes:
[image]

The switch comes with brackets to mount it in a 19-inch rack, but I can't find a way to mount the patch panel in the same rack. I can buy a 10-inch cabinet, but then I have nowhere to put the switch (and I can't find any switch that would fit in a 10-inch rack).

Is there a standard way to adapt a 10-inch device to a 19-inch rack? Or an I stuck with improvising my own bracket? (or buying a bigger patch panel?)

**Update 26th April:** I went for a new 19-inch patch panel, and put the lot into a 6U cabinet for good measure.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most obvious thing is to get a patch panel designed for a 19" rack or one that comes with an adapter plate.

If you have your heart set on using the patch panel that you have then you would be faced with creating something of your own. I believe that the easiest way to do that is to purchase a ready made blank 19" rack panel that is higher than your patch panel. You then cut out a rectangular hole in this blank panel to fit your patch panel which you can push through from the front and secure in place with machine screws through the existing ears.

BTW. Blank patch panels can be had in steel and aluminum materials. You may find one type to be easier to work with depending upon available tools.

Comment: Note that it is also possible to purchase ready made rack mount trays to which you can mount existing equipment. These typically would not close up the panel space where the tray mounts unless it also comes with an attachable panel that you can custom modify.

Comment: Customising a blank 19" panel is a nice idea, thanks - at least that way I only have the cutout to think about.

Comment: Then again, it's probably just as cheap to get a brand new 19" CAT6 panel (and my effort is just more time with the punch-down tool, not metalwork).

Comment: Tend to agree with you and you can always sell the narrow one online at the likes of Craigs List.